# May 2023 Writing Challenge: Secret Specialized Knowledge

Tags: discussion, topic-challenge

As decided by vote, here's the next challenge, proposed by [Mary](https://writing.stackexchange.com/users/44281/mary):

> Write a scene in which the point-of-view character reveals specialized knowledge by what he describes of what he sees, WITHOUT revealing the reason why. (A building contractor notices the concrete, a historian dates the statues both when they were made and what era they were faking, etc. But you aren't told about being a contractor, historian, etc.)

---

Go onward and write! Then post your story here as an answer, and get feedback in the comments. If you [ask a main site question](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) while writing for this challenge, leave a comment below this question or mention it in your answer.

Follow this question if you want to be notified instantly of any new answers.

You can also post and vote on future challenges here: [The next writing challenge could be yours](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2446/34330)